# Two dimensional array - sum 'row' and add as new element of array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array, which represents columns and rows of data.  I need to sum both the columns and rows, but I need to total from the the new 'summary' row.

Data (6x5 array)

```
[1, 0, 3, 0, 0], 
[0, 4, 0, 0, 4], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

so the result should be a 7x6 array

```
[1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4], 
[0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 8], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 12]
```

I know I can sum each column and add an additional row to my two dimensional array via

```
# Sum the columns, add additional one row for summary
a << a.transpose.map{|x| x.reduce(:+)}
```

but how do I add the additional column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.map! {|row| row + [row.reduce(:+)]}
```

[map!](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map%21) takes each element of the array, passes it to the block and replaces that element with whatever that block returns. So since we call it on a 2d array, `row` will be a 1d array - the row of the original array.

Then I calculate the sum with `reduce(:+)` of that row. Then I need to append it to that row. What I've done here is to wrap the result of sum into an array and then used [+](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/%2B) to concatenate those two arrays.

I could have also done this:

```
a.map! {|row| row << row.reduce(:+) }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Would you mind a short explanation in lay mans terms?

Answer (score 0):

As I was asking the question I came up with a solution, but I'd like to know if there is a better approach.

My solution

```
# Sum the rows (including the new summary row)
row_sum = a.map{|x| x.reduce(:+)}

# transpose the original array, add the summary column as a new row
c = a.transpose << row_sum

# transpose it back to the original view, now we have both summary of rows and columns
c.tranpose
```

**Update**

Here is my new short answer thanks to Jakub Hampl

```
# Create the summary column (row totals), update the array
a.map! {|r| r + [r.reduce(:+)]}

# Create the summary row (column totals)
a.transpose.map{|x| x + [x.reduce(:+)]}
```